# 'Releasing' iterators on a list in Java

Tags: java, collections

I'm trying to write a game engine, in which a list of list of sprites is used to hold all sprites (The list of lists lets me order the sprites in a sensible manner). The problem is, I need to repeatedly add and remove sprites, something that violates the fail-fast iterators pretty quickly, giving me a concurrent modification exception. Can I have multiple iterators on a list, and will this stop the exceptions? Failing this, is there a way to 'release' a list's iterator, so that the list no longer checks for modifications?

Comment: What about just marking which sprites need to be removed and then removing them in groups?

Comment: I've done that, but there's still the problem of adding the sprites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have multiple iterators on a list, and will this stop the exceptions?

Yes you can, and no it won't.  (The iterator checks the state of the list to determine if a concurrent modification has occurred.)

> Failing this, is there a way to 'release' a list's iterator, so that the list no longer checks for modifications?

No there isn't, at least not with the standard list classes.  And it would be a bad idea because it would be likely to lead to the kind of anomalies and data corruptions that fail-fast iterators are designed to avoid.  (Would you prefer your application to fail predictably with a ConcurrentModificationException, or fail occasionally with random data structure corruptions and/or weird exceptions?)

I think you need to look at alternative List implementation class in which the iterators allow concurrent modifications.  Depending on how your application is using the list, the possibilities include:

- `CopyOnWriteArrayList` this has full list semantics, but write operations tend to be a bit expensive.
- `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` this most of the operations you'd expect on a list (but not positional insert or remove), and write operations are cheaper.

In both cases, the iterators provide weaker guarantees about whether or not the iteration will see all elements.  You need to read the respective javadocs carefully to be sure that the semantics are suitable.

With a couple of historical exceptions, the collection types in `java.util` are not designed for concurrent / multi-threaded use cases.  If your application requires collection types that are accessed by multiple threads, you need to look at the implementations in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: Tell him about `java.util.concurrent...`

Comment: also google collections - guava has some concurrent implementations that might be worth a look.

Comment: It's not concurrent. The lists are referred to in a single thread, but the addition and removal is done independent of the traversal which results in the unfortunately-named ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @DaedalusUsedPerl - It doesn't matter, they will work.  (If you can think of a better / more appropriate name than `ConcurrentModificationException` I'd be interested to hear it ...)

Comment: `UnauthorizedModificationException`, `UnsafeModificationException`, `IReallyWishThisWasAnUnnecesaryException`, `OhWaitItIsException`, `YesIAmALittleIrritatedWithThisException` all come to mind.

Comment: `IteratorBrokenException`, `IteratorDesynchronizedWithCollectionException`, ... I guess there are even more.

Comment: 1) `UnauthorizedModificationException` blatantly misleading.  2) `UnsafeModificationException` why is it unsafe?  Because it was done concurrently with the iteration.  In fact it is the iteration that is unsafe, not the modification.  3) `IteratorBrokenException` vague and misleading.  (The iterator isn't broken ... it was just used incorrectly.)  4) `IteratorDesynchronizedWithCollectionException` - the meaning is about right, but a 45 character class name is a FAIL.

Comment: My point is that the current name does actually say what has happened ... a modification was made to the collection concurrently with the iteration represented by the iterator object.  And I can't think of an exception name that would say it better.  (And besides, the name is fixed and no amount of complaining is going to make any difference.  Which makes these comments moot ... of course)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over a list's contents as they exist at a particular time, independent of any modifications that happen while your iteration is in progress, you should simply make a copy and iterate over the copy.

This may sound scary from a performance point of view, but I'd encourage you to try it out and only consider alternatives (like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`) if profiling actually indicates that creating the copies is a hot spot in your finished application.  The garbage collector is pretty good at making short-lived objects like these copies perform very well.